# Why does ERR trap not work for a command in double-ampersand (&&) exit with non-zero value

Tags: bash, shell

I know that you can catch fail command with `set -e` and `trap 'exit' ERR`, but when I tried

```sh
trap 'exit' ERR

true && echo "from true"
false && echo "from false"
echo "end"
```

I got this

```
#result
from true
end

#what I want
from true
```

I know I can do something like this

```
true && echo "from true" || exit 1
false && echo "from false" || exit 1
```

but I have to do it every line that I use `&&`

Comment: Avoid using `set -e` or `trap ERR` in real world scripts. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Comment: It does work in that scenario, but the way it works is not how you expect.  IOW, what you are seeing is the designed behavior. If this is confusing, consider that one more data point that demonstrates why you should never use `set -e`

Answer (score 1):

Redefine `echo` in your script by a function that exits:

```
echo () {
    builtin echo "$@"
    exit 1
}
```

If you need `echo` without `exit` somewhere, rename the function to `echexit` or whatever and use it in the appropriate places.